# Blazor Webassembly "Cannot read property 'style' of null" after navigation to new page

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly

I have tried to navigate from one Page to another with this this line of Code:

```
navigationManager.NavigateTo($"/SecondPage");
```

The navigation works, but I get the following error after the second page is loaded:

[image]

Does anyone know a solution to this error?

**Edit:**

I changed

```
navigationManager.NavigateTo($"/SecondPage");
```

to

```
navigationManager.NavigateTo($"/SecondPage", true);
```

This causes, that the site is requested from the server.

[Navigationmanager Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.navigationmanager.navigateto?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

That made the error disappear.

But that is not really what I want.

Comment: I think the error is in the `SecondPage`, can you show it?

Comment: @Stefan I have removed everything except for this line

`@page "/SecondPage"`

 in the second Page

Comment: @Stefan If I open the page without the `navigationManager.NavigateTo($"/SecondPage");` the error is not there.

Comment: Well... that is odd : /

Comment: No repro (of course). Did you change anything in the included js or css?  Create a [mre] based on a new app from a default template.